# find('list') between model with i18ns return an empty array

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I'm using cakePHP 2.3.5 with CakeDC User & I18n plugin.

I create 2 tables, user_detail_group and user_detail_fields, which user_detail_fields belong to user_detail_group.
Both tables relates to i18n tables.

When I want to get the list of user_detail_group to put in the selection using
$userDetailGroups = $this->UserDetailField->UserDetailGroup->find('list');

it return an empty array

I also try to using inside the controller
$this->loadModel( 'UserDetailGroup);
pr( $this->UserDetailGroup') );

it also return an empty array

If the model not connect with i18ns table, its work properly. It's only model that related with i18ns have this problem.

Comment: I figure out whats wrong.
Im using Configure::write( 'Config.languages', array( 'en-us', 'es-us' ). When I'm change using underscore en_us. The relation works.

But now it not loading the pot file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Cake TranslateBehavior on lib/Cake/Model/Behavior is using locale 'en_us', which I'm using en-us on my bootstrap. 
I change the TranslateBehavior on _getLocale function from 
$Model->locale = $I18n->l10n->locale; 
to 
$Model->locale = $I18n->l10n->lang; 
It's work